# Restore option-left and option-right in MacOS terminal - What is the action sequence?

Tags: terminal, macos, shortcut

In my terminal, in settings->profiles->keyboard, I set some shortcuts for option-left and option-right. When I realised that these had overwritten the default "move to beginning/end of word" behaviour, I deleted them. However, now that shortcut doesn't work at all.

For example, the shift+left shortcut says `\033[1;2D`. Does anyone know the magical incantation for beginning/end of a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following settings:

- Option Left is `\033b`
- Option Right is `\033f`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! It's silly that they don't have a "restore defaults" button.